# i want to disable options that are not matched with the data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have this list of days of doctor's practice days in database

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="hari_praktek" style="width: 100%;">
     <option value="-" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Hari Praktek</option>
     <option value="Monday">Senin</option>
     <option value="Tuesday">Selasa</option>
     <option value="Wednesday">Rabu</option>
     <option value="Thursday">Kamis</option>
     <option value="Friday">Jumat</option>
     <option value="Satuday">Sabtu</option>
     <option value="Sunday">Minggu</option>
 </select>
```

and i plan to create consultation form for the patient. i want that whenever i choose a doctor. the dropdown list that i'm gonna make will show days & dates which only days that are matched with doctor's practice day that are not disabled, others are disabled. i will use ajax and i want to know how i make the fetch file that takes practice's day from database and compare them with the days from date function. thank you in advance.

edit:
this the doctor's name drop down

```
<label for="nama_dkt">Nama Dokter</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" name="nama_dkt" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Dokter</option>
              <?php
              $query  = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT id,nama_dkt FROM dokter");
              while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              ?>
                <option value="<?= $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['nama_dkt']; ?></option>\
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nama_dokter').change(function() {
    var dktid = $('#nama_dokter').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'fetch.php',
      data: {
        id: dktid
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#tgl_konsultasi').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
$koneksi = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'simklinik');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT hari_praktek FROM jadwal_praktek WHERE dokter_id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
$output = [];
for ($day = 0; $day < 21; $day++) {
   $output[] = strtotime(sprintf('+%d days', $day));
}
$out = '';
foreach ($output as $day) {
   $date = date('l', $day)
   $out .= "<option value='" . date('l', $day) . "' ' . (($result['hari_praktek'] != $date) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : "") . ' >" . date('l d F Y', $day) . "</option>";
}
echo $out;
?>
```

it doesn't work the way i want to.

Comment: At least you should let us know what you have attempted (please post the ajax and the PHP script it calls)

Comment: Is this a mysql problem (you can select the right data from mysql), or is it a php problem (you cannot pass the selected data onto the client side) or is this an ajax problem (can't bring the data to the client side) or is this a js problem (cannot update the GUI)?

Comment: I think its ajax problem cause the dropdown list doesnt display anything

Answer (score 0):

Your forming of the option tags looks a little funky to me.

Perhaps in your loop you could try changing to this

```
foreach ($output as $day) {
  $date = date('l', $day);
  $disable = $result['hari_praktek'] != $date ? " disabled=disabled" : "";
  $out .= "<option value='" . $date . "'" . $disable . ">" . date('l d F Y', $day) . "</option>";
}
```